# What's the best way to typeset C++ codes in latex?

Tags: packages, sourcecode

I'm participating in a programming contest and we are allowed to prepare a team reference document which must not exceed 25 pages. Typically we will prepare many code templates and this year I'm trying to use latex to typeset these C++ codes and I want to know what's the best way to do that.

Some requirements:

1. Since there is a page length limit I want to typeset my codes as compact as possible.
2. I want to have the C++ codes syntax highlighted.
3. If it is possible to generate a compact table of content in front, it would be best.

Comment: I'd recommend the `listings` package. And yes you should be able to obtain a TOC, by escaping to LaTeX in the code -- this should be done so that the LaTeX is treated as comments to C++.

Comment: You can also consider the `minted` package, although it requires the external python program `pygmentize`. I personally prefer the `minted` output, but `listings` output is easier to customize.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recently I have finished my thesis, and I added an appendix with some CINT (C/C++) code. I     used `listings` package, adding those lines on my preamble:

```
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,    
%   rulecolor=,
    language=[GNU]C++,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=false,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        numbers=left,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
        numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
%        \lstdefinestyle{C++}{language=C++,style=numbers}’.
}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
  language=C++,
  captionpos=b,
  tabsize=3,
  frame=lines,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
%  identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
  keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
  commentstyle=\color{Darkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{red}
}
```

The output I get looks like that:

[image]

Comment: It says "! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `darkgreen'." when I try to compile this. Any idea why?

Comment: @Julian_W : Add the following to your preamble `\usepackage{xcolor} \definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}` . Please let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes, thank you! I thought darkgreen was a predefined color 

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I'd do it with my [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package, which uses the Python Pygments library for highlighting.  The PythonTeX package provides a listings environment, using `newfloat`.  I've created a command `\codeline` that allows you to insert references to specific lines of code in the list of listings as well.  `\codeline` must only be used in comments, so that it will be processed (automatically and correctly) during code highlighting.  Also, for it to work properly, you must give each listing a caption *before* actually entering the code (otherwise, the order in the list of listings is off).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pygopt={texcomments=true,style=emacs}]{pythontex}
\setpythontexlistingenv{listing}

\newcounter{sublisting}[listing]
\newcommand{\codeline}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{lopytx}{listing}%
    {\protect\numberline{\hspace{0.5in}\thelisting.\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}\hspace{0.5in}#1}%
}

\begin{document}


\listoflistings


\begin{listing}[h!]
\caption{Hello, world}
\begin{pygments}[numbers=left]{c++}
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; //\codeline{Important code line!}
}
\end{pygments}
\end{listing}


\begin{listing}[h!]
\caption{Hello, world, again!}
\begin{pygments}[numbers=left]{c++}
# include <iostream>

int main() //\codeline{Another important line}
{
   std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; 
}
\end{pygments}
\end{listing}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @G. Poore. I'm wondering how I can use this package, I don't know how to communicate it with the texmaker. All packages I worked until now are automatically installed..

Comment: If I decide to write some Tex code as example will this solution appropriate?